# aptana studio 3, recognize php files

Tags: php, aptana, aptana3

aptana recognizes template files and has different colors

but when I open a php file, the color is all the same

Comment: does the php file has the `<?php` opening tag and/or is saved as .php file? Please be clearer and provide more details

Comment: file has <?php opening tag and is saved as .php file

Answer (score 0):

1.Check Prefereces: General > Editors > File Associations

Is *.php files associated with php editors?

2.Check Prefereces: General > Content Types

Is PHP Content Type include *.php file?